# How to pop-up a Particular Range of cells which is in the last row(s) onto a MsgBox (if possible) or a Popup window?

Tags: excel, vba

This is a Follow up question to a previously "Solved" question. 
Please go through the previous code to get the idea. 
here: [How to prevent a row from copying into another workbook when the range has no data while using 'LastRow' 'xlUp'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55672775/how-to-prevent-a-row-from-copying-into-another-workbook-when-the-range-has-no-da/55672975#55672975)

I have managed to successfully copy and paste a certain range (containing values) onto another workbook. Now to check if the data was entered, I use the '*Cltr+Down Arrow*' button to goto the last cell with value. The problem is, since there are people using this who have little to no knowledge on computers, they accidentally press the wrong buttons which could erase a cell value. So I need to make a Macro to find the last range pasted. 
     I managed to use a MsgBox to show the last row column 'A's value.

```
Sub LastUsedRow_SpecialCells_1()
Dim LastRow As Long
LastRow = ActiveSheet.Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell).Row
 MsgBox LastRow
End Sub
```

But I need the MsgBox to display the range as well since the code pastes multiple rows depending on the number of rows entered.

One more method I found was this

```
Sub test()
    Dim r As Range, ary
    Dim LastRow As String
    LastRow = Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    Set r = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A1:R1")
    ary = Application.Transpose(Application.Transpose(r.Value))
    MsgBox Join(ary, " ")
End Sub
```

But this only shows the first row as I have not defined the Last row function.. then again I need a range consisting of multiple rows.

Comment: if you want the whole set between A1 and R LastRow... you need  `Set r = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A1:R" & LastRow)` this will give you the whole range. But again, not sure if you want this.

Comment: `MsgBox Join(ary, " ")` doesn't work when I add that. It says "Runtime error '5' : Invalid Procedure call or argument"

Comment: So you want to concatenate all the values in a 2d range? Think you'll need a loop.

Comment: Not in a second range. I want the (Last time I clicked the button to paste range of data) to show on a Msg Box with a click of a button/shape. I hope I'm clear.

Comment: "2d"=2 dimensional, not second.

Comment: Oh sorry, I completely missed that. Haha. Yes, but I want it to be displayed onto a msgbox or a popup window.